# i want to push notification when i recieve a message from mqtt broker

Tags: android, flutter, dart, push-notification, mqtt

I'm working on flutter app ( notify user when a raspberry pi detect a movement). Everything works fine.

1. connecting the flutter app to mqtt broker
2. subscribing to the topic
3. getting the messages from the mqtt broker and i can see them in console log

My problem is that I want to push notification when I get a message from MQTT broker. i tried "flutter_local_notification" but all what I could find is tutorials working with triger buttons.

```
void _subscribeToTopic(String topicName) {
    print('Subscribing to the $topicName topic');
    client.subscribe(topicName, MqttQos.atMostOnce);

    // print the message when it is received
    client.updates?.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>>? c) {
      final recMess = c![0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;
      final message =
          MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMess.payload.message);
      print('YOU GOT A NEW MESSAGE:');
      // i want to push notifation
      print(message);
    });
}
```

Comment: What have you tried and how didn't it work?

Comment: i tried with flutter_local_notification but i couldn't make it work since all the tutorials works with  buttons to push notification ( u need to press a button to push notification )

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72247673/edit) the question to show what you tried and how it failed and then somebody may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: i updated my question hope i can get a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution , i created a notification service with "fluter_local_notification" then i called the shownotification function when i get a message from mqtt broker.

```
void _subscribeToTopic(String topicName) {
print('Subscribing to the $topicName topic');

client.subscribe(topicName, MqttQos.atMostOnce);

// print the message when it is received
client.updates?.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>>? c) {
  final recMess = c![0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;
  final message =
      MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMess.payload.message);
  print('YOU GOT A NEW MESSAGE:');
  // i want to push notifation
  NotificationService()
      .showNotification(1, 'check your mailbox', 'you have new mail', 1);
  print(message);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you, I use `flutter_local_notification` package and send notification when receiving mqtt message, but I have a problem is the program will only show notification when I open the program, it will not show when I close the program . Therefore, to make it run in the background you need to use a cloud message service, for example firebase provides this service for free, you can check flutter push notification to learn more.